# Will/will have?

Tags: future

Which of these two variants is correct (or more appropriate)?

> Sean said, "once we've ended this, things **will have changed** completely and we will be able to help"
>
> Sean said, "once we've ended this, things **will change** completely and we will be able to help"

Comment: I'd prefer 'Sean said, "By the time we've ended this, things will have changed completely ..." .' for the first sense.

Comment: Both are completely correct and equally appropriate in the right context. They both make sense and are both perfectly usable.  They just mean different things, and without knowing what Sean is talking about in some detail, it's impossible to know which is better for your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Once we've ended this" refers to the moment after or at the moment 'this' is ended.

So you need to determine when 'things' change to decide which sentence to use.  If 'things' change **after** or **at the moment** 'this' ends, you'll want the second option.  Like @Edwin Ashworth suggested, The first option suggests that by the time 'this' has ended 'things' **have already** changed.